# The Software keyboard flashes after popup window pops up and dismiss. Does anyone know what to do?

Tags: android

The Software keyboard flashes after popupwindow pops up and dismiss. Does anyone know what to do? on the recyclerView

Comment: You can try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` under activity it will hide keyboard until user not focus on any edittext.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, when the keyboard is open, on showing popup window, the keyboard hides, and appears again.  Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve popup closing outside window I used `isFocusable = true`

I change it to another logic, and this resolved problem with the keyboard `flashing`

```
isOutsideTouchable = true
setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(context.resources, ""))
```